# how to image resizing woocommerce oceanwp

Tags: image, woocommerce, resize

i have a question about image re-sizing.
is there any way to resize photos with css or php without cropping them?(woocommerce cropping feature is not the way) Also I have tons of photos already published in my website and to resize them one by one would be pain in the...

What should i do to fix this problem ?
example of what i got

https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3aWn.png
tried

```
img {
  width: 30%;
  height: auto;
}
```